# quotes removed in powershell $args

Tags: function, powershell, quotes

I have following function

```
function rsynce {
  & echo $args
  & rsync -e '/usr/bin/ssh' $args
}
```

and by calling

```
PS X:/> rsynce -avP --exclude '''folder''' ~/Downloads dev:~/Downloads
```

I get

```
-avP
--exclude
'folder'  <= '' present (the wanted behavior)
~/Downloads
dev:~/Downloads
```

but with

```
PS X:/> rsynce -avP --exclude 'folder' ~/Downloads dev:~/Downloads
```

I get

```
-avP
--exclude
folder <= '' removed (the unwanted behavior)
~/Downloads
dev:~/Downloads
```

Is there a generic way to avoid that I need to type `'''folder'''` instead of `'folder'`

Thanks for the help

***Update***

This

```
function rsynce {
  & echo "$args"
  & rsync -e '/usr/bin/ssh' "$args"
}
```

results in

```
-avP --no-links --exclude folder ~/Downloads dev:~/Downloads
rsync: -avP --no-links --exclude folder ~/Downloads dev:~/Downloads: unknown option
```

called in powershell.

Comment: This can be done in the shell you are calling the script from and also within the powershell script. So what is the shell you are using? or try putting the quotes in the powershell file, so `& rsync -e '/usr/bin/ssh' "$args"`

Comment: @Otter Please see the update

Comment: When PowerShell passes variable values as arguments to external programs on Windows, it double-quotes them _as needed_ -  based on whether the value contains spaces - when it rebuilds the command line to use for actual invocation behind the scenes. Unless you want the `'` to be _part of the value to pass_, don't use `'''folder'''` - the target program will see verbatim `'folder'`.

Comment: When you're running native apps in windows like that, you need to use `"` double quotes rather than single, on things like filepaths